# How to return unauthorized in Micronaut HttpServerFilter using Kotlin

Tags: security, micronaut

Being a newbie to both Kotlin and Micronaut, I'd like to write a simple HttpServerFilter that would check the incoming http request headers.

If it contains a specific X-API-Key value, then proceed otherwise return unauthorized.

Something like:

```
class APIKeyFilter: HttpServerFilter {
  override fun doFilter(request: HttpRequest<*>?, chain: ServerFilterChain?): Publisher<MutableHttpResponse<*>> {
    val apiKey = request.headers.get("X-API-Key")
    if (apiKey == null || !Base64.getDecoder().decode(apiKey).contentEquals("your-api-key".toByteArray())) {
      return HttpResponse.unauthorized()
    }
    return chain.proceed(request)
  }
}
```

Given the return is a Publisher, how could this be achieved?

I tried following the documentation, but it's very complicated for something that seems very simple. https://docs.micronaut.io/latest/guide/#filters

Answer (score 1):

I have this code instead this works

```
    return HttpResponse.status<Any>(HttpStatus.FORBIDDEN)
        .header(
            HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE,
            MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON
        ).body(
            ErrorResponse
        )
        .toPublisher()
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work:

```
class APIKeyFilter: HttpServerFilter {
  override fun doFilter(request: HttpRequest<*>?, chain: ServerFilterChain?): Publisher<MutableHttpResponse<*>> {
    return if (hasApiKey(request)) {
      chain!!.proceed(request)
    } else {
      Mono.just(HttpResponse.unauthorized<Any>())
    }
  }
}
```

Perhaps the Mono.just could be replaced with something more appropriate but I'd have to investigate other options.